# Theory of probability.

Tags: probability

Theory of probability.
The random vector (x, y) has a density:
$ f(x,y)=Cxy ;  0\leqslant x \leqslant 2, 1 \leqslant y \leqslant 3 $
Find the constant C.
How can I do it?

Comment: Well, what properties of probability functions do you know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
$$C\int_{X}\int_{Y}f_{XY}(x,y) dydx= 1.$$ Then

$$C\int_0^2\int_1^3 xy dy dx = 1,$$ where

$$\int_0^2\int_1^3 xy dy dx = \int_0^2 4x dx = 8.$$

Finally, we have that $$C = \frac{1}{8}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Massive hint:
$$
C\int_{X}\int_{Y}f_{XY}(x,y) = 1
$$

Comment: I got $ c=1/8 $. Well?

Comment: @olikalady seems legit